# Parse file into bash function for bashrc

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a function in my bashrc to make executing a python script I wrote easier, along with piping the output. Please see example:

```
function pythonfunction()
{
    script.py $filename | less
}
```

I'd like the execute the function, referencing a file, i.e.

```
pythonfunction testfile.txt
```

Apologies if this is super simple, I can't see to find the answer anywhere..

For reference, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Unknown Option: testfile.txt
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: The error message comes from your Python script, not from Bash.

Comment: The Python script functions correctly outside of bashrc however.. Is there any other way of doing this @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
function pythonfunction()
{
    script.py "$1" | less
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error :/.. Is there any other way of doing this?
I also get errors:
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook

This python script function correctly if I run it like:
script.py $filename | less

Comment: You're getting what error exactly?  If you put the above into a file by itself and then add `pythonfunction testfile.txt` below, and run that script using `bash THESCRIPT`, what happens?

Comment: Apologies, tmux was caching my previous update to my .bashrc. It's working now, many thanks